# How to stop overriding the files in module's config.xml in magento?

Tags: magento

Actually my module is overriding two files. My module is overriding the default search. Here is the code :-

```
<models>
<catalogsearch>
<rewrite>
<indexer_fulltext>WY_SearchIndex_Model_Catalogsearch_Indexer_Fulltext</indexer_fulltext>
<layer>WY_SearchIndex_Model_Catalogsearch_Layer</layer>
</rewrite>
</catalogsearch>
...
```

Now what I want is I am doing my module enable/disable from admin & suppose it is disabled from admin it should not override those 2 files above & thus default search will run.

Now I can't put ifconfig in this config.xml right? like this :-

```
<models>
<catalogsearch ifconfig="searchsphinx/general/enabledornot">
```

So what can be done? What I did right now - put condition in one of the file i.e. my module's Layer.php file like this -

```
if(!Mage::getStoreConfig('searchsphinx/general/enabledornot'))
{
//This will call default module's search...there is no method inside the below class
    class WY_SearchIndex_Model_Catalogsearch_Layer extends WY_SearchIndex_Model_Catalogsearch_Layer_Extends
    {
    }
}
else
{
//This will call my module's search
class WY_SearchIndex_Model_Catalogsearch_Layer extends WY_SearchIndex_Model_Catalogsearch_Layer_Extends
    {...}
}
```

I know this is very bad way but I am thinking if the module is disabled from admin then the above files should not be overridden.

How can I do it? Any suggestion please?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do a conditional rewrite, however I'm not sure if it is considered a valid practice. But anyway,

1. Remove rewrites from config
2. Insert into your config.xml the following

   ```
   <global>
   ...
       <events>
           <controller_front_init_before>
               <observers>
                   <wy_search_rewrite_classes>
                       <type>model</type>
                       <class>searchsphinx/observer</class>
                       <method>rewriteClasses</method>
                   </wy_search_rewrite_classes>
               </observers>
           </controller_front_init_before>
       </events>
   ...
   </global>
   ```
3. Create Observer.php file in Model folder (if you don't have one)

   ```
   class WY_SearchIndex_Model_Observer
   {

   ...

       /**
        * Rewrite necessary classes
        *
        * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
        */
       public function rewriteClasses(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
       {
           $isRewriteEnabled = Mage::getStoreConfig('searchsphinx/general/enabledornot');
           if ($isRewriteEnabled) {

               Mage::getConfig()->setNode('global/models/catalogsearch/rewrite/indexer_fulltext',
                   'WY_SearchIndex_Model_Catalogsearch_Indexer_Fulltext');

               Mage::getConfig()->setNode('global/models/catalogsearch/rewrite/layer',
                   'WY_SearchIndex_Model_Catalogsearch_Layer');

           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This looks promising Alexei. Thank you very much :)
This will probably solve my issue :) I will get back to you after implementing that what happened after implementation.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Hi Alexei, This is working totally fine :)
Your solution is more fair & productive what I were trying :)

Thanks again for helping :)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Magento admin disable module is actually disable module output and with custom modules it may not work as intended/at all.

If I'm correct in understanding that you do NOT want this module to function in the admin panel:

```
if( Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin() )
{
    // Code...
```

If you want a conditional instead your approach is correct - you can also extend the admin interface to provide a way to edit your module's config in the admin panel:

> http://inchoo.net/magento/create-configuration-for-your-magento-extension/

Comment: Hi Vladimir,

Actually I want the custom module to work in admin panel. I had given an option in admin that Module Enable/Disable - Yes/No. If user select Yes then only my module's custom search should work else magento's default search should work

Issue was in my module's config.xml file, there is written <rewrite> & it is rewriting 2 files but I want to put condition that if my module is disabled in admin then those 2 files should not be rewritten....so if those 2 files would not be rewritten then default search would automatically work :)

Thanks for your answer Vladimir :) & helping me :)